# Why my String is returning as a blank string?(JAVA)

Tags: java, string

I am trying to return a string with time but somehow the returned string blank. I don't know what is the right way to do it.

```
static String timeConversion(String s) { 
     int hr=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
     String min=(s.substring(3,5));
     String sec=(s.substring(6,8));
     String ap=s.substring(8,10);
     String res="";
     if(ap=="AM")
     {
         if(hr==12)
         {
             res.concat("00"+":"+min+":"+sec);
         }
         else
         {
             res.concat(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
         }
     }
     else if(ap=="PM")
     {
         hr=hr+12;
         res.concat(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
     }
     return res;
}
```

Comment: Can you check what are getting in ap variable

Comment: I can't remember in Java, but doesn't `concat` return a String (since Strings are immutable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int hr=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,2));
 String min=(s.substring(3,5));
 String sec=(s.substring(6,8));
 String ap=s.substring(8,10);
 String res="";

 System.out.println(ap) //see the value of ap in the console
 if(ap=="AM")// do ap.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")
 {
     if(hr==12)
     {
         res.concat("00"+":"+min+":"+sec);
         System.out.println(res) //see console and try res = res.concat ...

     }
     else
     {
         res.concat(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
         System.out.println(res) // see console

     }
 }
 else if(ap=="PM")
 {
     hr=hr+12;
     res.concat(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
     System.out.println(res)

 }
  System.out.println(res)
  return res;
}
```

you can also try to use + e.g `res = res + ("00"+":"+min+":"+sec);`
you can also try using stringBuilder

i think your question is more like.. "how can i debug my code";
with the above solution. you will figure out where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

- Since strings are immutable, you must assign the result of `.concat(String)` to the variable if you want it to be updated.
- Comparing strings must be done using `.equals()`

With that in mind...

```
static String timeConversion(String s)
{
    // Expecting a string in the format "HH:MM:SSAM" or "HH:MM:SSPM"
    int hr = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 2));
    String min = s.substring(3, 5);
    String sec = s.substring(6, 8);
    String ap = s.substring(8, 10);
    String res = "";
    if (ap.equals("AM")) {
        if (hr == 12) {
            res = res.concat("00" + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
        } else {
            res = res.concat(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
        }
    } else if (ap.equals("PM")) {
        hr = hr + 12;
        res = res.concat(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
    }
    return res;
}
```

As another note, while `concat` is OK in small doses, if you're concatenating multiple strings in a function/method (for example, in a loop), use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.